# Stored procedure / view accesses another db on same server (security issue)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, security, certificate

I have an application that uses a view in database A on a Microsoft SQL Server which performs a SELECT query against a different database B on the same server. This is a production SQL server. The problem is that, the server user account has only permissions to access database A. Thus, when the server runs the view select query, it gets the error:

"The server principal "...." is not able to access the database B under the current security context.

It seems like we have to use the VIEW this way and it's too risky to grant access to database B for the server (IIS, which hosts the app)

Is there a way for the server to get the data using the VIEW select query by using like a certificate or similar?

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You can either setup a stored procedure with admin privileges to gt results, or run a bat cmd using SQLCMD.EXE to get results.  The bat file could be run with different privileges.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

SQL Server has the `execute as` clause to do exactly what you want (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx)).  This clause is available both stand-alone and as an option to `create procedure`, `create function`, and `exec`.  For instance, you can run the query using a user (security context) that has full permissions.

You can also define a function to run in the security context of the owner rather than the caller (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) particularly Example A).  It is easy to replace a view with an inline table-valued function; you might have to define a full table-valued function.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the user to the second database but forbid it from doing anything except selecting from that `VIEW`. Create a special role, grant `SELECT` permission on that role to the view, then add the user to that role (and remove it from `public` and all other roles).